# If $X_{n} \xrightarrow{d} X$ , then show that $X_{n}^2 \xrightarrow{d}X^2$.

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, convergence-divergence, weak-convergence

Let $X_{n} \xrightarrow{d}  X$ , then show that $X_{n}^2  \xrightarrow{d}X^2$ converges in distribution to $X$.

Comment: No personal input, not even a precise definition of convergence in distribution, much needed as explained in an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution of the exercise depends on your definition of convergence in distribution. It's almost trivial if it is $\int f(X_n)\mathrm d\mu\to \int f(X)\mathrm d\mu$ for each $f\colon\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ continuous and bounded since if $f$ is such a function, so is $t\mapsto f(t^2)$ and more generally $t\mapsto f(g(t))$ where $g$ is continuous.

If the definition if $F_n(t)\to F(t)$ when $F$ is continuous at $t$ and $F_n$, $F$ are the corresponding cumulative distribution function, then use the fact that for $t\geqslant 0$, 
$$\mu\{X_n^2\leqslant t\}=\mu\{|X_n|\leqslant \sqrt t\}=\mu\{X_n\leqslant t\}-\mu\{X_n\lt t\}.$$